# gradle: No tests found for given includes: [ro.idea.ToggleTest.testIsAd]

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

[This is my screencast and my code](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B08GAyjqgToLbUZXMkc0ZzA3M3c&usp=sharing), see my screencast, i use standard testSrc and i can run `gradle test` succeed, but when i run `gradle test --test ro.idea.ToggleTest.testIsAd`, it failed.

**my question is:** How to fix it?

In settings.gradle, i set following code:

```
include ":ro"
project(':ro').projectDir = file("../ro")
```

**my guess** it's reason cause this error, but i don't how to fix it

Comment: FYI, you can replace all of the above with `includeFlat "ro"`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth "ro" is not a child dir in root, i hope "ro" can     be in any path so i use above code, and this is key point in this question, can you tell my why "gradle: No tests found for given includes", i wanna know how to list all "given tests" and how to specific "given tests"