# Gradle: how to list all "given tests"

Tags: java, testing, groovy, junit, gradle

I try the following code:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea $ gradle test --tests "ro.idea.ToggleTest.testIsAd"
:ro:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:ro:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ro:classes UP-TO-DATE
:ro:jar
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:ro:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:ro:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ro:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:ro:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ro:test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [ro.idea.ToggleTest.testIsAd]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The output show "No tests found for given includes", **my question is:** how to list all "given tests" and how to specify "given tests"

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830295/gradle-no-tests-found-for-given-includes-ro-idea-toggletest-testisad) is my old question

Answer (score 15):

I am unsure about list all the given tests prior to executing since I don't believe this is known until the testing actually executes.

What you could so is add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
test {
  beforeTest { descriptor ->
     logger.lifecycle("Running test: ${descriptor}")
  }
}
```

Then if you go:

```
gradle clean test
```

It will run all tests but will also print out the test descriptor before it executes providing the `method(className)` which will look like so:

```
:test
Running test: test testC(org.gradle.MySecondTest)
Running test: test testD(org.gradle.MySecondTest)
Running test: test testA(org.gradle.MyFirstTest)
Running test: test testB(org.gradle.MyFirstTest)
```

Alternatively you can just run the previous command without the `build.gradle` file change and look at your `build/reports/tests/index.html` file which will show all tests run.

So then you could specify a single test with:

```
gradle clean test --tests "org.gradle.MyFirstTest.testA"
```

Or all tests in a class:

```
gradle clean test --tests "org.gradle.MyFirstTest"
```

Or all tests in a package:

```
gradle clean test --tests "org.gradle.*"
```

Comment: as @NicholasDiPiazza said, this does not list the tests - only changes the output.

Comment: The trick for me was to not use the quotes. So `gradle clean test --tests org.gradle.MyFirstTest`

Comment: what would be for Kotlin equivalend?

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili Currently, no direct way to do this in the Kotlin version. A feature request has been opened here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5431
As a workaround, you can register a TestListener, as demonstrated in this resource: https://technology.lastminute.com/junit5-kotlin-and-gradle-dsl/

Answer (score 7):

You can also use:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```